# Angular new date range filter bug?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-daterangepicker

Angular 10

I'm trying to set both startDate and endDate of Angular Date Range filter back to null, but it seems like when setting startDate to null, the endDate get auto-injected with the previous value.

In the picture below, `this.selectedTimeFrame.startDate` and `.endDate` are both null at first, but after running `this.filterGroup.get('startDate').setValue(null)`, the endDate is not null anymore.

```
this.selectedTimeFrame = {
   id: selectedTimeframe.id,
   startDate: selectedTimeframe.start(),
   endDate: selectedTimeframe.end()
};

this.fromRadioBtn = true;
this.filterFormGroup.get('startDate').setValue(null);
this.filterFormGroup.get('startDate').setValue(this.selectedTimeFrame.startDate);
this.filterFormGroup.get('endDate').setValue(null);
this.filterFormGroup.get('endDate').setValue(this.selectedTimeFrame.endDate);
```

Can someone explain? or point out if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but try to use `patchValue()` or `reset()`.

Docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue